# Regenerate JS function in partial postback after full posrback

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, updatepanel, registerstartupscript

My server-side ASP.NET code generates a JS function (actual function, e.g. *function Foo() {...}*) on initial page load using ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript. That function becomes part of ASPX markup and executes when client calls it.

The problem is: I need to modify that function's code in server-side partial postback (Update panel). But when I generate the function with the same name *function Foo() {...}* via ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript it doesn't seem to take effect - original function generated in PageLoad's ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript is called.

Is there any way to regenerate client-side function in partial postback after it had been generated on initial page load?

Thanks!

Comment: Got it (from http://codecorner.galanter.net/2012/05/22/regenerate-javascript-function-code-in-asp-net-partial-postback-after-initial-load/)

Function *Foo* needs to be declared as a variable in client-side code first, e.g.

    var Foo;

and then in the *RegisterStartupScript* script generation use *Foo = function() {...}* instead of *function Foo() {...}*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered in my first comment to the question.